# Editable/method call throwing java.lang.nullpointerexception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

First, I just want to say that the stackoverflow community is empowering to say the least.  Trying to build my first two apps, currently deployed but trying to knock out a couple classes while in Africa.

So, I'm making a pretty basic protein tracking app. Forgive my excessive comments, it keeps my head straight as I'm trying to figure this stuff out.

I've looked up and found a lot of answers to previous issues but I have no idea how to progress with this.

[How to calculate EditText value in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965063/how-to-calculate-edittext-value-in-android)

I started with that, and it's been great (thank you luvieere), but I think that the editable that I made is freaking out a bit.  My logcat in eclipse is calling out that line as well as my calculating method.

It's probably just something simple, but from what I've seen it's such a broad error that you'll just have to look at these terrible lines of code to see where I strayed wrong.  Thanks again for the help people, and this is my first time putting up a question, so let me know how to give you mad rep. :D

Some code:

```
public class anitasProteinTracker extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnOverviewSnapshot, btnNomNoms, btnSettingsCalculate;
    EditText etSettingsProteinGoal, etWeight;

    <//random code here//>

    btnSettingsCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettingsCalculate);
    btnSettingsCalculate.setOnClickListener(this);

    <//random code here//>

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    <//random code here//>

    case R.id.btnSettingsCalculate:

        //clicking this will find the value and set it to the goal edittext
        calcProteinGoal();   <---This line showed up in logcat

        break;

    }
}

private void calcProteinGoal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Editable etWeightlbs;    <----this is the other error line in logcat
    double weightlbs = 0;
    double weightkgs = 0;
    double proteinMultiplier;
    double gProtein = 0;

    //get the weight from the user and ensure it's a number
    etWeightlbs = etWeight.getText();

        if (etWeightlbs != null)
            weightlbs = Double.parseDouble(etWeightlbs.toString());
            //convert lbs -> kgs
            weightkgs = weightlbs / 2.2;

    //get spinner value
    //don't know how to do that yet, going to set the variable
    proteinMultiplier = 0.8;

    //set up protein goal   
    gProtein = weightkgs * proteinMultiplier;

    etSettingsProteinGoal.setText(String.valueOf(gProtein));
```

some logcat:

```
07-03 21:41:14.405: W/dalvikvm(1861): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.joemac.anitasprotein.anitasProteinTracker.calcProteinGoal(anitasProteinTracker.java:119)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.joemac.anitasprotein.anitasProteinTracker.onClick(anitasProteinTracker.java:102)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-03 21:41:14.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Only because I don't see it in there...  You're doing `findViewById` for the EditText as well right?  All I see is a binding for the button.

Comment: Oh snap! David, /highfive brother.  Yup, totally missed it.  Noob mistake, but I like how you still checked on that, instead of getting deeper into it.  You rock!  Post it in the answer spot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only because I don't see it in there... You're doing findViewById for the EditText as well right? All I see is a binding for the button.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks David!  Good eyes.